# how to autofill data by selecting employee name here?

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo

I have to get all data auto-fil if I select emp name then it other fields should auto fill.
Here I have added the tree view **.py** and **xml** file please help me for this,
And I want one more filed for attachment to particular employee.

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv

class hr_employee(osv.osv):
    _inherit="hr.employee"
    _columns={
        'emp_line':fields.one2many('empl.line','emp_id','Employee Line'),
    }

class empl_line(osv.osv):
    _name="empl.line"
    APPOINTMENT_SELECTION=[
        ('0','Regular'),
        ('1','Aditional'),
        ('2','Deputation'),
        ('3','Incharge'),
    ]
    _columns = {
        'name':fields.selection(APPOINTMENT_SELECTION,'Appointment For'),
        'surname':fields.char('Name'),
        'doj':fields.date('Date of Joining'),
        'dor':fields.date('Date of Relieving'),
        'emp_id': fields.many2one('hr.employee', 'employee_id'),
    }

empl_line()



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<openerp>
    <data>
        <record id="hr_view_employee_form1" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">hr.employee.form</field>
            <field name="model">hr.employee</field>

            <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">

                 <page string="HR Settings" groups="base.group_hr_user" position="after"> 

                    <page string="Employee Details">    
                        <field name="emp_line" >
                            <form string="Employee Line">
                            <group>
                                <field name="name"/>
                                <field name="surname"/>
                                <field name="doj"/>
                                <field name="dor"/>

                            </group>

                            </form>
                            <tree string="Employee Line">

                                <field name="name"/>
                                <field name="surname"/>
                                <field name="doj"/>
                                <field name="dor"/>


                            </tree>
                        </field> 
                    </page> 
                </page>

            </field>


        </record>

        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="hr.view_employee_form2">
                <field name="name">hr.employee.form</field>
                <field name="model">hr.employee</field>
                <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_form" />
                <field name="arch" type="xml">
                        <page string="Personal Information" groups="base.group_hr_user" >
                            <attribute name='invisible'>1</attribute> 
                        </page>
                </field>
            </record>

    </data>
</openerp>
```

Comment: please send me solutuon

Comment: onchange is the best solution, set onchange for the emp_name.

Comment: please i need code for that i know that concept but getting error at some point

Comment: you should post the code here, and also the error msg that you get. So we can help you..!!

Comment: i want one sample code like on change method i am not getting what i need to do with it .just post one code with 2 fields if i select field 1 field 2 should be auto fill and post .xml and .py file

Answer (score 0):

You can use onchange function and return values you need.

To do so, set on_change attribute to your field:

```
<field name="name" on_change="onchange_name(name)" />
```

and in your *.py* file, add a function like this to your model:

```
def onchange_name(self, cr, uid, ids, name, context=None):
    # Put your logic here
    return {
        'value': {
            'surname': 'this is a surname'
        }
    }
```

So the surname will be changed when changing *name* field.